# group function is not allowed here (sql-oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

**I want to update saboloo with the following table**

```
update sagani 
set saboloo=sum(sagani.qula + sagani.shualeduri + sagani.finaluri) 
where sagnis_id='9';
```

Comment: you will have to use a subselect (a select sum(....) from table ...) in your update statement.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor I can not understand what you mean

Comment: @koki: see the answer below from gordon linoff

Comment: Yes, I saw and corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation is not allowed in an `update`, because `update` changes values in the *rows in the table*; once the data is aggregated, the connection to the original rows is lost.

I can imagine that you mean one of two things.  The first would be a simple sum within the row:

```
update sagani 
    set saboloo = (sagani.qula + sagani.shualeduri + sagani.finaluri) 
where sagnis_id = 9;  -- looks like a number so I assume it is a number
```

Alternatively, you may want to update multiple rows with the same value added up from all those rows:

```
update sagani s
    set saboloo = (select sum(s2.qula + s2.shualeduri + s2.finaluri)
                   from sagani s2
                   where s2.sagnis_id = s.sagnis_id
                  )
where s.sagnis_id = 9;
```

Your question doesn't have enough information to infer your intention, although the use of `sagnis_id` suggests that there is only one row and you don't want aggregation at all.

Comment: i have 1 question, can you answer?

Answer (score 0):

SUM is not applicable here as your requirement is very straight forward. You can try this following script for your purpose-

```
UPDATE sagani 
SET saboloo=(sagani.qula + sagani.shualeduri + sagani.finaluri) 
WHERE sagnis_id='9';
```